# How to make the ids of an embeddable class unique together spring data jpa so that no duplicates can be entered

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, nhibernate-mapping

I have 3 tables `User`, `Book` and `Review`. `Review` has an EmbeddedId I want to make unique so that there are no duplicates of a user reviewing a book more than once. Thanks in advance.

```java
@Entity
public class Review {
    
   @EmbeddedId
   private ReviewCompositKey id;
   
   // ....
}


@Embeddable
public class ReviewCompositKey implements Serializable {
    
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
   private Long userId;
   private Long bookId;
   //  ....
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    
   User user = new User("John", "Doe", "john@example.com",
             "testpass", "testpass", "admin", true);
   user = userRepository.save(user);
      
   List<String> authors = Arrays.asList("Blake", "Jane");
   Book book = new Book("Just A Trial", "123456789abc", "1940", 
                           authors);
   book = bookRepository.save(book);
      
   Review review = new Review(new ReviewCompositeKey(user.getId(), 
                             book.getId()), (byte)4, "First Title");
   review = reviewRepository.save(review);
    
   Review review1 = new Review(new ReviewCompositeKey(user.getId(), 
   book.getId()), (byte)4, "First Title");
   review1 = reviewRepository.save(review1);
       
}
```

Comment: Your `@EmbeddedId` annotation already makes the review unique... did you want help with the other tables or was the question about the Review class?

Comment: Thank you for responding. It was just about the Review class the reason i asked is because when i created a review with the same user and book twice it worked so i was wondering if they were unique together.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the whole code, but from what I'm looking at, you shouldn't be able to do that.  You're not initializing the `userId` and `bookId` though, so maybe it's using a random Long of some kind?

Comment: I edited the code maybe this will clarify the issue a bit

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, after iterating over the Reviews table I only had one instance of the same comment it did not duplicate them. The reason I was confused was that I was Expecting it to throw an exception when a user attempts to duplicate Reviews.